# Write JSON Model in XML table - loop through items

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5, xmltable

When writing my JSON data into the cells of my xml table, all the data are displayed below each other in only one column. The Column headers though, they get displayed correctly in individual columns. (My data comes from an excel file I'm uploading) Please advise me where my mistake is:

```
<m:Table id="testdata3">
<m:columns>                                 <!-- Columns created in controller -->
</m:columns>
<m:items>                                   <m:ColumnListItem id="columnsListItem" press="onPressListItem"  type="Navigation">                                   <m:cells>  
<!-- Cells created in controller -->    
         </m:cells>                         
        </m:ColumnListItem>
</m:items>
</m:Table>
```

controller:

```
_import : function(file) {
            var oTable = this.getView().byId('testdata3');
            if(file && window.FileReader){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var result = {}, data;
                var that = this;
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    ... not relevant code ..
                    var aColumns = that.getColumnNames(worksheet);
                    var aData = that.getRowData(worksheet, result);     
                    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                    oModel.setData({
                        columns: aColumns,
                        rows: aData
                    });
                    oTable.setModel(oModel);
                    oTable.bindAggregation("columns", "/columns", function(index, context) {
                        return new sap.m.Column({
                            header: new sap.m.Label({
                                text: context.getObject().columnId
                            })
                        });
                    });

                    oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", function(index, context) {
                        var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

                        if(roa.length > 0){

                            result[worksheet] = roa;

                        }
                        for(var i = 0; i < roa.length; i++){

                            return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                                cells: [
                                    new Text({ text :context.getObject().cellId })
                                    ]
                            })
                        };
                    });

                };
            };
        },
```

Here's a screenshot of the output data:
[image]

Comment: You add one cell for multiple columns. You should add as many cells to you items binding as there are columns.

Comment: I edited my answer with dynamic cells. If you copy this, it will work.

Comment: @MatthijsMennens I copied your code and now what happens is that simple everything gets set in the column headers and the rest of the table is empty :O

Comment: @MatthijsMennens I have to edit that comment, since it's not EVERYTHING that's in the column headers.. it's only some parts of the table body that gets moved up to the headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

Try this example, please.

```
    onChange: function(oEvent) {
        var file = oEvent.getParameter("files")[0];
        var oTable = this.byId("testdata3");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var that = this;
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var wb = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: "binary"
            });

            var firstSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
            var worksheet = wb.Sheets[firstSheetName];
            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var aColumns = that.getColumnNames(worksheet);
            var aData = that.getRowData(worksheet);
            var aCells = that.getCells(aData);

            oModel.setData({
                columns: aColumns,
                rows: aData
            });

            oTable.setModel(oModel);
            oTable.bindAggregation("columns", "/columns", function(index, context) {
                return new sap.m.Column({
                    header: new sap.m.Label({
                        text: context.getObject().columnId
                    })
                });
            });

            oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
                // CHANGE ACCORDINGLY OR MAKE DYNAMIC
                cells: aCells
            }));
        };

    },

    getColumnNames: function(worksheet) {
        var oColumns = [];
        var cells = Object.keys(worksheet);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(cells).length; i++) {
            if (cells[i].indexOf("1") > -1) {
                var columnName = worksheet[cells[i]].v;
                oColumns.push({
                    columnId: columnName
                });
            }
        }
        return oColumns;
    },

    getRowData: function(worksheet, result) {
        var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);
        return data;
    },

    getCells: function(aData) {
        var cells = [];
        var keys = Object.keys(aData[0]);
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = new sap.m.Text({
                text: "{" + keys[i] + "}"
            });
        }

        return cells;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but aCells doesn't contain data, so it's just empty.. I'm confused

Comment: Did you retrieve the cells after you retrieved the columns?

Comment: Did you add aColumns to the parameter for the getCells function?

Comment: oTable.bindAggregation("items", "/rows", function(index, context) {

      for(var i = 0; i < aColumns.length; i++){

       return new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
         new Text({ text :context.getObject().cellId })
         ]
       })
      };
     });

I tried this

Comment: my cellData is sotred in the aData variable, isn't it?

Comment: You didn't add the aCells to the cell when binding the items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180461/discussion-between-matthijs-mennens-and-sonja).

Comment: I know but I don'T know where to add it.. i need the cellID to retrieve the data?